# javascript rendered collection_select outputs HTML option tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

How can I fix the javascript so that the HTML doesn't show in `collection_select` such as the `<\/option>\n`, `<\/select>`, `<\/div>');`

This is the **HTML output** before javascript kicks in:

```
<select name="duel[duelers_attributes][1][challenge_id]" id="duel_duelers_attributes_1_challenge_id"><option value="29">Climb Mount Everst by May 20, 2017</option>
<option value="24">Run by Feb 20, 2017</option>
<option value="26">See Drive-thru Movie by Feb 20, 2017</option>
<option value="28">Run 5 Miles on Weekdays for 10 Days Starting Jan 20, 17</option>
<option value="25">Bungee Jump by Feb 20, 2017</option>
<option value="27">Journal on Weekdays for 10 Days Starting Jan 20, 17</option></select>
```

This is the **HTML output** after javascript kicks in:

```
<select name="duel[duelers_attributes][1][challenge_id]" id="duel_duelers_attributes_1_challenge_id">$("#dropdown-no-2").html("\n   <option value="\&quot;\&quot;">&lt;\/option&gt;\n</option><option value="\&quot;24\&quot;">Run by Feb 20, 2017&lt;\/option&gt;\n</option><option value="\&quot;25\&quot;">Bungee Jump by Feb 20, 2017&lt;\/option&gt;\n</option><option value="\&quot;26\&quot;">See Drive-thru Movie by Feb 20, 2017&lt;\/option&gt;\n</option><option value="\&quot;27\&quot;">Journal on Weekdays for 10 Days Starting Jan 20, 17&lt;\/option&gt;\n</option><option value="\&quot;28\&quot;">Run 5 Miles on Weekdays for 10 Days Starting Jan 20, 17&lt;\/option&gt;\n</option><option value="\&quot;29\&quot;">Climb Mount Everst by May 20, 2017&lt;\/option&gt;&lt;\/select&gt;\n&lt;\/div&gt;")</option></select>
```

[image]

**_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@challengers.collect { |challenger| [challenger.id] }) %>

<%= f.select :challenge_id, options_for_select(@challenger_challenges.collect { |challenged| [challenged.full_challenge, challenged.id] }) %> ,

# The problem occurs only AFTER the javascript kicks in and replaces the above line with collection_select(:dueler...
<script>
$('#duel_duelers_attributes_1_user_id').change(function () {
    var user_id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var address = "<%= user_challenges_path %>/".concat(user_id);
    $.get(address, function(data) {
        $("#duel_duelers_attributes_1_challenge_id").html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

**routes**

```
  get 'duels/user_challenges/:id', :to => 'duels#user_challenges', as: 'user_challenges'
  get 'duels/user_challenges/:id/:user_id', :to => 'duels#user_challenges', as: 'select'
```

**user_challenges.js.erb**

```
$('#dropdown-no-2').html('<%= j render partial: "user_challenges" %>')
```

**_user_challenges.html.erb**

```
<%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true, id: 'dropdown-no-2') %>
```

**AJAX console output**

```
$('#dropdown-no-2').html('<select name=\"dueler[challenge_id]\" id=\"dueler_challenge_id\"><option value=\"\"><\/option>\n<option value=\"24\">Run by Feb 20, 2017<\/option>\n<option value=\"25\">Bungee Jump by Feb 20, 2017<\/option>\n<option value=\"26\">See Drive-thru Movie by Feb 20, 2017<\/option>\n<option value=\"27\">Journal on Weekdays for 10 Days Starting Jan 20, 17<\/option>\n<option value=\"28\">Run 5 Miles on Weekdays for 10 Days Starting Jan 20, 17<\/option>\n<option value=\"29\">Climb Mount Everst by May 20, 2017<\/option><\/select>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime rendering and manipulation of js code depend on use of single `'` and double `"` quotes in js.erb file.

Try change:

```
$('#dropdown-no-2').html('<%= j render partial: "user_challenges" %>')
```

to

```
$('#dropdown-no-2').html("<%= j render partial: 'user_challenges' %>")
```

This might seems funny answer but it work on most cases.

Comment: Try html_safe on rendred html. `$('#dropdown-no-2').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'user_challenges').html_safe %>")`